# jdk.js in back-end is very slow

Tags: magento-1.9, backend, third-party-module

My back-end page is keep loading in sometimes like this.

[image]

I found out that is because a download of javascript file `jdk.js` from http://community.thegiantdata.com/jdk/ takes too long.
Sometimes, I even need to wait few minutes. Is there any way that I can make it quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably something from a 3rd party module. You could download the file, find the reference in the layout XML file that loads it and point it to the local version but it might have negative effect since the content from the remote source could be dynamic.

Optionally, contact the company (MageGiant I think it is) and ask them whats up

Comment: I would go with #1

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt unless it loads some dynamic content based on variables or the origin domain. Can't imagine tho...

Comment: If they do this, this module should be removed.

Comment: you are right. It is come from a free module (magegiant/community)